# What's the difference between o/b/o and c/o

Tags: recording, music-business

Often times when reading the publishing credits of a track I come across the terms `o/b/o` and `c/o`.

[image]
[image]

From what I understand:

- **o/b/o:** *on behalf of*
- **c/o**: *care of*

With all that being said what's the main difference between the two? In theory they sound exactly the same.

Comment: This is now sort-of the ***third*** time you've asked this. Look, deciphering such credits is basically guesswork. Perhaps there are rules, but most likely their exact wording is part of an agreement between those parties. You'd be better off looking at the relevant entries in ASCAP's and BMI's databases (and other such sources).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about any possible technical usage in publishing credits, but typically "A in care of B" just means that B is doing nothing but passing it along to A, whereas "A on behalf of B" means that A is doing actual work of some sort as an authorized representative of B.

So not only is the direction from representative to principle reversed, but one describes a more functionally significant relationship than the other.

Comment: For addresses, c/o is often used to indicate that some third party is acting as a contact address for another, which seems similar to the usage of c/o here.